# How to convert this json string to jobject

Tags: c#

How to convert this json string to **Jobject**

```
"{\"user\":{\"id\":373697,\"username\":\"luckygirlxxx123\",\"counter_rechecking\":0,\"user_id\":76131,\"fb_id\":\"100047460285611\"}}";
```

I need it convert to Jobject like this because i need it to post data to website api . **Example :**

```
        JObject concac = new JObject();
        concac1["id"] = 373697;
        concac1["username"] = "luckygirlxxx123";
        concac1["counter_rechecking"] = 0;
        concac1["user_id"] = 76131;
        concac1["fb_id"] = "100047460285611";
```

Because It inside **USER** that i dont know how to create jobject with that

Answer (score 0):

this code might help you.

```cs
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonData = "{\"user\":{\"id\":373697,\"username\":\"luckygirlxxx123\",\"counter_rechecking\":0,\"user_id\":76131,\"fb_id\":\"100047460285611\"}}";  

        var details = JObject.Parse(jsonData);  
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(details["user"]["id"], " " + details["user"]["username"]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is by giving those JSON values to the contracture of the object

```
public JObject(int id, string username, int user_id ....)
```

then you declare object and you pass values to it

```
JObject concac = new JObject(concac1["id"], concac1["username"], concac1["user_id"]..... );
```

The second way is [JSON Serialization And Deserialization In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: The problem is alll ID , Username , etc is in User